# What is the highest degree this polynomial can have?

Tags: polynomials, roots

Let P be a polynomial and its coeficiants are 1 or -1. and all roots are real number. What is the highest degree this polynomial can have?

By the integer root theorem. $\pm1$ maybe a root.

I think smth may be wrong with the problem. I mean if k is an odd number $x^k-x^{k-1}+x^{k-2}-...x^2+x-1$ polynomial has only root 1?
Edit:my example fails I guess. there are k-1 complex roots

Comment: Why do you say that $\pm 1$ are roots?  They're the only possible rational roots of the polynomial, but that doesn't mean they _are_ roots.  Consider the polynomial $x^2-x-1$, which has all roots real but has neither $+1$ or $-1$ as roots.

Comment: Polynomials with all coefficients $\pm1$ are called *Littlewood polynomials*, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Littlewood_polynomial – you might find some useful stuff if you search for that term.

Comment: @Gerry Myerson thanks for the comment but I couldnt find anything about its roots

Comment: For $n\le20,$ the greatest value is $n=3.$